# I want to send a string from one react-native app to another react-native app using bluetooth

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

Which is the best library for react-native for sending data using Bluetooth and how to implement that any tutorial or steps for it?

Comment: Next time google search first.

https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

Comment: @Sheelpriy Checked about ble-plex library but no proper methodology/tutorial in their documentation on how can i can connect to the second device and send a string.